# app works perfectly fine on emulator but crush on OnePlus device without any ANR. Just showing - Access denied finding property "sys.thermal.para"

Tags: android

I'm working with REST API (Retrofit) to retrieve some data (String).

In API 24 app it is working fine, but in API 21 & API 28 (it could be more) the application crashes without any crash report. It is in the logcat showing this line simultaneously.

Issue: **Access denied finding property "sys.thermal.para"**

A few day ago I got a blog post(lost that), and according to that it is a security issue for API 28.

When the Internet connection is off the app doesn't crash, it works properly without fetching data from the server. After connecting to the internet the Application crashes simultaneously and doesn't show any crash report.

I expect the outcome will be the app won't crash while internet connection is on and data will fetch properly.